# What is the logic used to calculate that maximum number of threads can be created in any windows machine?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

**What is the logic used to calculate that maximum number of threads can be created in any windows machine**?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit broad. It depends on the CPU architecture. A thread can be created if enough memory spaces are available for a given program. Which is 2GB for 32bit user mode program.

[Read this thread experiment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773)
more about [Memory limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx)